# How to fix build failed error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know how to fix this issue in Android Studio. By the way I'm pretty new to android development & if someone could help me that would be great.

So this is basically what I'm getting in the editor.
[build failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuj5D.jpg)

And this is my build.gradle file

[build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D5hG.jpg)

I'm using Android Studio version 3.1.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some linking issue is causing the error. You can try to close android studio and  delete .gradle folder and .idea folder from file explorer and reopen the android studio it will recreate the directory and resolve any linking issue that are there.

If this doesnt solve the issue then there may be some code error in your project. You should check the code for any non-resolved linking issue in java or xml file..